# cakephp pages not updating without browser refresh

Tags: cakephp

I am working on a site using cakephp 2.10. It appears that the pages do not update unless the browser is refreshed. For example, I sign in as a user, it redirects me to the last page I was on before I left the previous time. (Correct function). But, when I go back to the main page, it shows me signed out. If I then refresh the page, it shows me signed in. I have tried clearing the files in the folders under app/tmp/cache/.... (persistent, model, etc) and I even tried turning debug to 3 to try and get the cache to refresh that way. I am baffled why this is working this way. Any thoughts would be appreciated. I have experienced this on three sites I am working on recently.

Comment: It's presumably browser caching, not server-side. Look up the Cache-Control header.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do we control web page caching, across all browsers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49547/how-do-we-control-web-page-caching-across-all-browsers)

Comment: It might be. I am trying to figure out how to implement that in cakephp specifically.

Comment: This was it!! I figured out how to do it in cakePHP using the Session Configuration. Thank you!!